# How to clean versioned maven artifacts in artifactory?

Tags: maven-3, artifactory

I have two Jenkins jobs that build our software.

One job runs when it detects a change in the repository. The other job runs nightly.

I want the nightly job to start from a clean slate, that is, build all the artifacts - jars, wars, poms, rpms, etc. On the other hand, I want the other jobs to use existing artifacts - I already do this.

For the nightly job, I delete the local .m2 repository. But how do I delete the appropriate version in artifactory? For example, if I'm building a 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT version, I want to delete ALL artifacts in artifactory with that version beforehand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Artifactory not deleting Unique Snapshots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905747/artifactory-not-deleting-unique-snapshots)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to delete old snapshots, you can set `Max Unique Snapshots` to 1 for your Artifactory local repository.  See [here](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Local+Repositories).

> "The maximum number of unique snapshots (of the same artifact) to store. Any number of snapshots above the max are automatically removed by age."

Hope that helps!

Comment: I checked, and we already have that setting in our artifactory.

Comment: I am not sure 1 is the best option there. You'll usually want to keep couple of them around (just in case the last one is broken).

Comment: In my case, I sincerely want to conciously delete ALL of the snapshots, e.g., ALL 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT artifacts. Yes I want a shotgun and want to shoot it, to express it metaphorically. I need to know "how," not whether I should or shouldn't.

Comment: The `Max Unique Snapshots` is working for me... Make sure you have it set to 1, not 0 (0 allows unlimited snapshots).  It's important to note that the cleanup for each artifact only happens when you push a new snapshot into artifactory.  If you have a bunch of existing snapshots for an artifact already, you need to publish a new snapshot to get it to clean up the old.