# JFrog cli deploy a single file to artifactory target directory

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I need to delete old snapshots from the Artifactory. For cleanup we recently configured Max Unique Snapshots to 5, but the garbage collector only deletes the old snapshots when a new snapshot is deployed.

How do I deploy a single file to the Artifactory using the JFrog-cli? I am unsure of which command to use from their documentation. https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory

Comment: I'm trying to use the API described here:   https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Registry#DockerRegistry-DeletionandCleanup

I am not able to get this to work in any way.   I just want to delete the 'latest' tag.

Comment: See also: https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-10507

Comment: @JoshuaDavis I found a duplicate of what I was looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905747/artifactory-not-deleting-unique-snapshots?rq=1 and someone had put a feature request that is still open https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-12255. I am going to edit my question to be more specific.

Comment: I'm actually trying to do something slightly different with docker images in Artifactory: I want to overwrite 'latest' with Jenkins, and just pushing the 'latest' works only the first time.  After that pushing latest does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deploy a single file to Artifactory using the CLI with the upload command, for example:

```
jfrog rt u froggy.tgz my-local-repo
```

For additional documentation about the upload command take a look at the JFrog CLI [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UploadingFiles)

Comment: exactly what I needed